# Is there any meaning to using several validation metrics in cross validation for logit models?

Tags: r, logistic, cross-validation, marketing

My question might be a bit dumb since I'm relatively new to analysises using k-fold CV, but here goes:

I want to compare two logit models using k-fold CV, and then compare with another model type on a held out test set.
Until now I have usually just computed one metric during the CV, which is the rate of incorrect classifications.

But would it make sense to compute other validation metrics for model selection? Such as pseudo-R^2 and Likelihood Ratio? Or do I select the one that has the lowest average rate of incorrect classifications, use it to make predictions on the test data, and then compute the validation metrics they have in common?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it does make a whole lot of sense**

---

The choice of the figures of merit you want to look at is completely independent of the choice of train/test scheme.

You should choose the figures of merit according to what is relevant for your model and application, and typically more than one figure of merit is needed to give you a good overview of the expected performance.

In particular,

- if you go for "hard" class membership output (as opposed to e.g. probabilistic output), you need check whether the working point/threshold is appropriate for your application. This typically means you'd need to consider at least 2 complementary figures of merit.
- Even if your application specification prescribes a figure of merit that is a fraction of tested cases (such as misclassification rate), you should consider proper scoring rules for model selection.

(As a side note: when going for figures of merit that aggregate several classes, such as misclassification rate, make sure the relative frequencies of the classes match  your application scenario or correct the figures of merit accordingly.)